# Using Javascript/jQuery to access HTML elements with improper id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zoho

I'm making a Greasemonkey script for someone to change the display of some of the fields their CRM(Zoho) created because they don't have access to change the rendered HTML.

This should be easy, BUT Zoho decided that creating proper HTML was too big a pain in the ass, I guess, and their HTML contains things like this:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="50" style="width: 100%;" class="textField" id="property(Phone)" name="property(Phone)"/>
```

The ID's contain spaces and parentheses, which aren't valid in ID attributes, and is preventing me from using either document.getElementById() to select them or from using jQuery to select them.

Does anyone have any ideas for how I could grab that element? Obviously I could grab it via its index in its parent element, or by traversing the DOM, but both of those would mean that if the order of the fields changed, the Greasemonkey script would stop working correctly because it would then be targeting the wrong elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the spaces and parentheses using backslashes:

```
$('#property\\(Phone\\)').val('jQuery selected property(Phone)!');
$('#ab\\ cd\\ ef').val('jQuery selected ab cd ef!');
```

Answer (score 1):

What browser is this for? Firefox, I assume, since you mention GreaseMonkey. But `document.getElementById("property(Phone)")` seems to work just fine in Firefox 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the brackets like this:

```
$("#property\\(Phone\\)")
```

Comment: You beat me by a minute, but you forgot the '#' at the start of your selector. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always do a document.getElementsByTagName('input'), then browse the results and match it with it's attributes (like it's type and name, class...). Not very efficient but the only way I know that will work with any order (since the id is invalid)...

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
if (inputs)
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
        if (inputs[i].type == 'text' && inputs[i].name == 'SearchValue')
            return inputs[i];
```

I'm pretty sure JQuery (or any other good framework) have an equivalent to this snippet...

Answer (score 0):

JQuery probably can't find it using #id syntax, but could probably find it using tagName[id=value] syntax...   try it, and good luck.  See the [jQuery doc](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEquals#attributevalue).