# jQuery Get Dropdown Selection from Passed-in Parameter (ID)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of dropdowns generated on my page which look as follows.

```
<select id="opt(1)">
  <option value="Edit">Edit</option>
  <option value="View">View</option>
</select>

<select id="opt(2)">
  <option value="Edit">Edit</option>
  <option value="View">View</option>
</select>


<select id="opt(3)">
  <option value="Edit">Edit</option>
  <option value="View">View</option>
</select>
```

etc.

I need to write a JavaScript function which will return, using jQuery, the current selection of a dropdown based on the Index, which is part of the ID.

```
function getDropdownSelection(index) {

var sel = $('#opt(' + index + ') :selected').text();
alert(sel);
}
```

This does not work. The problems are:

1. How do I escape the () in the ID
2. How do I pass in the parameter value inside the `$('..')`.

Comment: Possible dupilicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022549/using-javascript-jquery-to-access-html-elements-with-improper-id-attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

Add a class name to all the dropdowns

```
<select class="test" id="opt(1)">
..
</select>
<select class="test" id="opt(2)">
..
</select>
```

Then jQuery should be:

```
$(".test").on("change", function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Thank you but I have to use the jQuery selection syntax on the ID.

Answer (score 0):

### You mean this?

```
$(function() {
    $("[id^=opt]").on('change', function(){
        var id = this.id;
        /* Do something */
    }); 
});
```

- The selector `[id^=opt]` means `startsWith` and will get all matching `elements`. In this case, your `html` `select(s)`. Then you can do something else without creating extra `functions`.

---

### Another approach

```
$(function() {
    $("[id^=opt]").on('change', function(){
        var selTxt = $('option:selected', this).text();
    });
});
```

- This way you can get the `text` as you requested ***(not `value`)*** from a `selected` option.

---

***PS.** I really don't know why you are getting this more and more and more complex.*

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it:

```
function getDropdownSelection(index) {

var sel = $('#opt\\(' + index + '\\) :selected').text();
alert(sel);
}
```